# In Modern OpenGL, drawing filled circle with GL_TRIANGLE weird z-axis behaviour

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glut

I am trying to draw filled circle in modern opengl using GL_TRIANGLE. I am filling circle array for circle vertices, and then I am filling points array using circle vertices to use vertices in triangle.I am using vec4(homogeneous coordinates) and setting vertices z-axis value to 0.0 and using default projection which should be from -1 to 1 ranges for each axis. But somehow, I am getting all screen painted with color instead of circle. Weirdly when I set z-axis value of points other than [0-0.4] range, I can get circle be drawn and when I increase the value of z, it acts like perspective and no matter what I have set to radius, it is getting smaller when z is increased. I could not figure out why z value acts like that.

```
using namespace Angel;


const int NumVertices = 90;
const double PI = 3.141592653589793238463;

const GLint width = 500;
const GLint height = 500;

vec4 points[NumVertices];
vec4 colors[NumVertices];

vec4 circle[30];
vec4 color = { 1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };
vec4 center = { 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };

GLfloat radius = 0.5;

int Index = 0;

void triangle(int b, int c) {
    colors[Index] = color; points[Index] = center; Index++;
    colors[Index] = color; points[Index] = circle[b%30]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = color; points[Index] = circle[c%30]; Index++;
}

void fill() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        float angle = 2 * PI * i / 30;
        vec4 point;
        point.x = center.x + (GLfloat)cos(angle) * radius;
        point.y = center.y + (GLfloat)sin(angle) * radius;
        point.z = 0.0 ; // PROBLEM !!
        circle[i] = point;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 29; i++) {
        triangle(i, i + 1);
    }
}

void init()
{
    fill();

    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points) + sizeof(colors),
        NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(points), points);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), sizeof(colors), colors);

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader("vshader.glsl", "fshader.glsl");
    glUseProgram(program);

    // set up vertex arrays
    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
        BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    GLuint vColor = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
        BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(points)));

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("PirateFace");
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

vertex shader :

```
#version 150

in  vec4 vPosition;
in  vec4 vColor;
out vec4 color;

void main() 
{
  gl_Position = vPosition;
  color = vColor;
}
```

fragment shader :

```
#version 150

in  vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main() 
{ 
    fColor = color;
}
```

Comment: So why are you using homogeneous coordinates in the first place, and what do you set the `w` component to?

Comment: I am using for future purposes but I forgot to set w, thank you for your reply it solved my issue.

Comment: What kind of purposes whould require you to send homogenous coordinates to the VS? Sure, one can come up some scenarios, but in reality, I highly doubt that you will need it. You might still prefer using `vec4` for alignment reasons alone, though.But that does not mean that you send that component to the shader, nor that you need to initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using vec4(homogeneous coordinates)

You need to properly initialize the `w` component of your `vec4` values to `1.0`.

Note that you do not need to store homogenous coordinates in your input vertex arrays in most scenarios. You can keep the `in vec4` in the vertex shader and just use 3-dimensional vectors as input, and the GL will automatically extend the vector to `(x,y,z,1)`.